# Trouble using 2-way data binding in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on my first Angular project, and I'm stuck at a point with two-way data binding.

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.no</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of shoppingList, let i=index">
          <th> </th>
          <th>{{shoppingList[i]}}</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><button type="button" (click) ="onAddButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></th>
          <th><select class="form-control">
              <option (input)="selectedItemName=$event.target.value" ngDefaultControl *ngFor="let selectedItem of getProducts()" >{{selectedItem.name}}</option>
            </select></th>
          <th></th>
          <th><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {StaticDataSourceService} from './static-data-source.service';
import {ProductRepository} from './product.repo';
import {Product} from "./product";
import {ShoppingList} from "./shoppingList";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public shoppingList:String[]=[];

  public selectedItem:Product =new Product();

  public selectedItemName:String;

  title = 'app';
    constructor(private repository:ProductRepository){
    }

    getProducts():Product[]{
      return this.repository.getProducts();
    }

    onAddButtonClick(){
      console.log(this.selectedItemName);
    }

    addToCart(name:String){
      this.shoppingList.push(name);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve: I want to pass the value of the dropdown to the onAddButtonClick() method and add the value to an array(currently I'm just trying to print it). However, I keep getting the console output 'undefined'. I also was getting a number of errors and after going through a lot of posts on SO I added the ngDefaultControl which made the errors go away. What does ngDefaultControl do? Thanks in advance for both questions.

Comment: try to remove the ngDefaultControl. Also, it would be helpful if you can show the errors too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is your `option` elements are triggering the setting of `selectedItemName` during their change event. You're using the `input` event but I think you want to be using `change` and you want to attach it to the `select` element, not individual option elements.

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  (change)="selectedItemName=$event.target.value"
>
 <option *ngFor="let selectedItem of getProducts()" >{{selectedItem.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

You might need to set a `$watch` on the `select` element to react to events, in lieu of the data binding

Comment: thanks, I attached the event to the select instead of the option, and now it works, but only if I select a different option from the dropdown, i.e it doesnt print if I have the default option selected, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems that I see in your code.

1.

```
        <tr *ngFor="let item of shoppingList, let i=index">
          <th> </th>
          <th>{{shoppingList[i]}}</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
```

Why not use the `item` instead of accessing your array with the index.
Something like

```
          <tr *ngFor="let item of shoppingList, let i=index">
              <th> </th>
              <th>{{item.something}}</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
```

2. The reason you are getting undefined error is because your shoppingList does not have any items! You forgot to initialize it in your `constructor` or `ngOnInit()`.

I could go on like importing ShoppingList, that look like a model for your shoppingList, but you just used shoppingList:String[] instead. Try the solution above and let me know if you still need help.